# Python homogeneous to inhomogeneous plot line

Tags: python, opencv, geometry

I found an [article](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture19_6pp.pdf) which is about epipolar geometry.

I calculated the fundamental matrix. Now Iam trying to find the line on which a corresponding point lays as described in the article:

[image: s]

I calculated the line which is in homogeneous coordinates. How could I plot this line into the picture like in the example? I thought about transforming the line from homogeneous to inhomogeneous coordinates. I think this can be achieved by dividing `x` and `y` by `z`

For example, homogeneous:

```
x=0.0295
y=0.9996
z=-265.1531
```

to inhomogeneous:

```
x=0.0295/-265.1531
y=0.9996/-265.1531
```

so:

```
x=-0.0001112564778612809
y=0.0037698974667842843
```

Those numbers seem wrong to me, because theyre so small. Is this the correct approach?
How could I plot my result into an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `x`, `y` and `z` you have are the parameters of the "Epipolar Lines" equation that appear under the "line in the image" formula in the slides, but labelled `a`, `b` and `c` respectively, i.e:

> au + bv + c = 0

solutions to this are points on the line.  e.g. in Python I'd define `a` as some points on the picture's x-axis, and solve for `b`:

```
import numpy as np

F = np.array([
    [-0.00310695, -0.0025646,  2.96584],
    [-0.028094,   -0.00771621, 56.3813],
    [13.1905,    -29.2007,  -9999.79],
])

p_l = np.array([
    [343.53],
    [221.70],
    [  1.0],
])

lt = F @ p_l

# if you want to normalise
lt /= np.sqrt(sum(lt[:2] ** 2))

# should give your values [0.0295, 0.9996, -265.2]
print(lt)

a, b, c = lt.ravel()

x = np.array([0, 400])
y = -(x*a + c) / b
```

and then just draw a line between these points